# why am i getting “inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation”?

Tags: python, tabs, indentation

This is my code:

```
x = [];
y = [];

xx = []
xy = []


# variable to show if file openening worked

opened = 0;

# try to open file

try:
    readFile = open('xyData.txt', 'r');
    # if open file worked
    opened = 1;

except:
    # if opening file went wrong
    print('Some error occured!');

#next line same as if opened == 1
if opened:
    # read in data from the file line by line

    for line in readFile:
        # variable line now holds one of the lines
        # in the data file
        # split up in the string 'line' based on whitespace
        splitUp = line.split();





        # x = splitUp[0], y = splitUp[1]
        # append to arrays for x and y
        x.append(splitUp[0]);
        y.append(splitUp[1]);
        xx.append(splitUp[0]*splitUp[0]);
        xy.append(splitUp[0]*splitUp[1]);



    # close file
    readFile.close();

  print('done')
```

There is more to do however at this point I get:

```
run lobf.py
  File "/Users/paulbebb/Desktop/pyscripts/lobf.py", line 56
    x.append(splitUp[0]);
                     ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

and I cannot seem to work out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...because you've inconsistently used spaces and tabs in your indentation? Does (or can) your IDE/editor show you the whitespace?

Comment: Why are you ending all your lines with semicolons? You know you don't need them, right?

Comment: After highlighting all the code in the text editor (sublime text 2) i realised some bits where tabbed and some spaced. Thankyou for pointing that out @jonrsharpe .. as for the semi-colons just something a tutor told me to do.

Comment: Then give your tutor http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ and tell them this isn't C!

Comment: Your tutor never learned Python.

Comment: The course is supposed to teach general programming as opposed to just the python syntax so thats probably why.

Comment: I shall tell him he is upsetting people!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some weird mix of tabs and spaces.  Just stick to using only tabs or spaces.  The code below only uses spaces.  Try copy pasting the code below into your editor.

```
x = []
y = []

xx = []
xy = []


# variable to show if file openening worked

opened = 0

# try to open file

try:
    readFile = open('xyData.txt', 'r')
    # if open file worked
    opened = 1

except:
    # if opening file went wrong
    print('Some error occured!')

#next line same as if opened == 1
if opened:
    # read in data from the file line by line

    for line in readFile:
        # variable line now holds one of the lines
        # in the data file
        # split up in the string 'line' based on whitespace
        splitUp = line.split()





        # x = splitUp[0], y = splitUp[1]
        # append to arrays for x and y
        x.append(splitUp[0])
        y.append(splitUp[1])
        xx.append(splitUp[0]*splitUp[0])
        xy.append(splitUp[0]*splitUp[1])



    # close file
    readFile.close()

    print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

The indent on your print seems to be wrong...Try this...also you dont need `;` after every statement, as this is python

```
x = []
y = []

xx = []
xy = []

# variable to show if file openening worked

opened = 0;

# try to open file

try:
    readFile = open('xyData.txt', 'r')
    # if open file worked
    opened = 1

except:
    # if opening file went wrong
    print('Some error occured!')

#next line same as if opened == 1
if opened:
    # read in data from the file line by line
    for line in readFile:
        # variable line now holds one of the lines
        # in the data file
        # split up in the string 'line' based on whitespace
        splitUp = line.split()

        # x = splitUp[0], y = splitUp[1]
        # append to arrays for x and y
        x.append(splitUp[0])
        y.append(splitUp[1])
        xx.append(splitUp[0]*splitUp[0])
        xy.append(splitUp[0]*splitUp[1])

    # close file
    readFile.close();

    print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything has to be in spaces. Each tab is 4 spaces. I would make sure that you are tabbing 4 spaces instead of tab. Basically, make sure you don't have any tabs and just have spaces to indent.

Comment: That was my problem thanks! .. I just need to see the whitespace in my text editort to notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor should have an option how to handle the tab key. I know in notepad++ you can set tab to be x number of spaces while choosing in a specific language.